# What day of the week IS the Sabath on?

Tags: sabbath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Judaism celebrate Sabbath on Saturday and most Christians celebrate Sabbath on Sunday?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4/why-does-judaism-celebrate-sabbath-on-saturday-and-most-christians-celebrate-sabb)

We think that Sunday is the Sabath but the jews think that Saturday is the Sabath. If Saturday is the real Sabath, how did it get changed to monday?