# How do non-Sabbatarians interpret Revelation 14:12?

Tags: exegesis, revelation, ten-commandments, sabbath, law-and-gospel

Revelation 14:12 (KJV)

> 12 Here is the patience of the saints: here are they **that keep the commandments of God**, and the faith of Jesus.

I've seen [Sabbatarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatarianism) bring up this verse of Revelation as evidence that true Christians should keep the commandments of God, including the Sabbath commandment ([Exodus 20:8-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+20%3A8-11&version=KJV)). In fact, in a [related question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/40100/38524) posted on Hermeneutics.SE, the most upvoted answers tend to agree that Revelation 14:12 **at least** includes the 10 commandments (but possibly more). If that's true, then the Sabbatarian has a solid point here.

How do non-Sabbatarians interpret Revelation 14:12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is therefore now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus. For the law of the Spirit of life has set you free in Christ Jesus from the law of sin and death. For God has done what the law, weakened by the flesh, could not do. **By sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and for sin, he condemned sin in the flesh, in order that the righteous requirement of the law might be fulfilled in us**, who walk not according to the flesh but according to the Spirit. For those who live according to the flesh set their minds on the things of the flesh, but those who live according to the Spirit set their minds on the things of the Spirit. For to set the mind on the flesh is death, but to set the mind on the Spirit is life and peace. 
> For the mind that is set on the flesh is hostile to God, for it does not submit to God's law; indeed, it cannot. Those who are in the flesh cannot please God. You, however, are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if in fact the Spirit of God dwells in you. Anyone who does not have the Spirit of Christ does not belong to him. - Romans 8:1-9

In light of much of what the New Testament and Jesus Himself has to say about Love and about the Law and the Prophets:

> “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind. This is the great and first commandment. And a second is like it: You shall love your neighbor as yourself. **On these two commandments depend all the Law and the Prophets.**” - Matthew 22:37b-40

> **A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another**: just as I have loved you, you also are to love one another. By this all people will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another.” - John 13:34-35

> Owe no one anything, except to love each other, for the one who loves another has fulfilled the law. For the commandments, “You shall not commit adultery, You shall not murder, You shall not steal, You shall not covet,” and any other commandment, are summed up in this word: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” Love does no wrong to a neighbor; **therefore love is the fulfilling of the law.** - Romans 13:8-10

It is fair to conclude that those saints in Revelation 14:12 have kept the commandments of God, not in the letter of the Law but in Love.